# Why Junit test cases(Methods) should be public?

Tags: java, junit, public

I just want to know why the test cases (test methods) should be public
like this

```
public class SpiceLoginTest {
    @Test
    public void testShouldVerifyLoginRequest() {
    }  
}
```

but if I remove public access specifier from this method

```
    @Test
    void testShouldVerifyLoginRequest() {
    }
```

Output: java.lang.Exception: Method testShouldVerifyLoginRequest() should be public

so

1. What is happening behind the scenes?
2. Is it using reflection or what?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, the test runner is using reflection behind the scenes to find out what your test methods are and how to call them.

If the methods were not `public`, calling them might fail (because the SecurityManager gets to veto that).

Comment: Although, IntelliJ, by default, generated @Test methods w/o access modifier at all.

Answer (score 0):

This is almost certainly because JUnit creates some `main` class which calls all of your test methods for you. To call them, they need to be public.